# Processing LANDSAT 8 data in R (using packages Raster, RSToolbox, etc.) in order to calculate NDVI and land cover classification?

Tags: remote-sensing, ndvi, landsat-8, land-classification

I am analyzing several LANDSAT scenes from the LANDSAT 8 OLI mission (18 in total, all from Jan 2017 - cloud cover < 20%).

I now want to calculate the NDVI and do some land cover classification on these scenes using R and its RS packages, but first need to apply some corrections to these scenes.

If I'm correct, **I need to** (with examples of codes provided from `RStooolbox` and `raster` packages)**:**

**1. Do the DN calibration**

```
p198r053_rad<-radCor(p198r053, metaData = metap198r053, method = "rad")
```

**2. Apply an atmospheric correction**

```
p198r053_haze<-estimateHaze(p198r053, darkProp = 0.01, hazeBand= c("B1_dn", "B2_dn", "B3_dn", "B4_dn"))
p198r053_sdos<-radCor(p198r053, metaData = metap198r053, hazeValues= p198r053_haze, hazeBand= c("B1_dn", "B2_dn", "B3_dn", "B4_dn"), method="sdos")
```

**3. Apply a topographic correction (C-correction)**

using a DEM and `RStoolbox::topCor`

**4. Mask the clouds using the QA layer**

using `raster::mask()`

**5. Check the geolocation of each scene**

I don't know how to do so yet (*see questions below*).

**6. Calculate the NDVI for each scene**

using

```
ndvi_formula<-function(nir,red) {
  (nir - red)/(nir + red)
}
```

(i.e. bands 5 and 4 of L8 data - *but from which layer?? (see question below)*)

**7. Classify images according to land cover type**

(perhaps this should be done with the Semi-Automatic Classification tool in QGIS?)

**8. Check if all scenes have the same projection and reproject if necessary**

Using `raster::projection()` and `raster::projectRaster()`

**9. Create a mosaic of all scenes for NDVI and land cover layers**

Using `raster::merge()`

**10. Crop mosaïcs to match the country's borders**

Using a shapefile of the country and `raster::mask()`

(I have based my approach on the one given by Wegmann *et al.* (2016) in "Remote Sensing and GIS for Ecologists using Open Source Software")

Are these steps correct and in the right order?

Also, more specifically:

- Steps 1-4 seem to create different rasters for each scene, how do I merge these rasters together to have a scene with all corrections from which to calculate NDVI and do the classification?
- How do I correct the geolocation of my scenes?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE MarieL. Please narrow this post into a single, focused question then vote to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

If you download surface reflectance data from [espa](https://espa.cr.usgs.gov) you can skip steps 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6, and you will benefit from a more advanced atmospheric correction.

**Mask the clouds using the QA layer**

```
maskFun <- function(x, y){
    x[y %in% c(322, 386)] <- NA
    return(x)
}

# r is the raster* object you want to mask and mask a RasterLayer with
# mask values (e.g. pixel_qa layer in espa products)
overlay(r, mask)
```

Adjust the masking values to your need (see [Landsat 8 SR product guide](https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/lasrc_product_guide.pdf))

**Classify images according to land cover type**

Do you have training data?
If yes it's a classification and you can train the classifier of your choice (randomForests, glm, randomGLM, ...), if not it's a clustering, and you also have many clustering options (kmeans, dbscan, meanshift). [Here](https://github.com/loicdtx/quickLandCover)'s a quick tutorial on how to perform a classification using R.

**Check if all scenes have the same projection and reproject if necessary** and **Create a mosaic of all scenes for NDVI and land cover layers**

There's no easy way to do that with `raster*` classes (`merge` and `mosaic` only work on rasters with same projection); your best shot if you want to do the two in one step is to use `gdalwarp`, which can be called directly from R using the `gdalUtils` package.

A good reference for the modelling part is the dismo package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dismo/vignettes/sdm.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! The ESPA asks for a scene list - I do have all my scenes in folders called (f. ex.:) "LC08_L1TP_199052_20170103_20170312_01_T1". What format does that list have to be? A text file?      I do have training data - thanks for the tutorial - I will have a look at it.

Comment: Yes, a text file, with one scene name per line will work.